# What does circular measurement stand for?

Tags: trigonometry

This is a problem in S. L. Loney. I am confused about what this phrase, "The circular measure", stands for in this problem. 
If the circular measure of two angles  of a triangle are respectively 1/2 and 1/3, what is the number of degrees in the third angle?

Comment: Is this english?

Comment: I'd presume, radians (since the alternative "portion of a full revolution" wouldn't give a triangle).

Comment: It isn't usual, but I have heard radian measure being referred to as "circular measure".  If that's what is happening here, you should be able to look up the definition and properties of radian measure to solve your problem.

Comment: "this is a problem in s l loney i am confusing that what this word" Can anyone decypher this?

Comment: @5xum Could be an author name, like "In Hungerford..."

Comment: Why the downvotes, with no reasons? The OP (new to the site) is confused and has asked a reasonable question.

Comment: "s l loney" probably refers to [S. L. Loney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S._L._Loney), a mathematician who wrote at least seven books.

Comment: @RoryDaulton You're right about Loney - see my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

The sum of the angles of a triangle is 180 degrees (angular measure), which is $\pi$ in circular or radian measure. It's just half a circle, or a straight angle.

Therefore the third angle of your triangle is $\pi - 1/2 - 1/3$ radians. Now convert that circular measure to degrees and you're done.

Google will do that for you. Put

> (3.14 - 1/2 - 1/3) radians in degrees

in the search bar and you find out that

> (3.14 - (1 / 2) - (1 / 3)) * radians =
>   132.162265 degrees

The reference seems to be this really old text.

Plane trigonometry, by S.L. Loney.
Loney, Sidney Luxton, 1860-

http://quod.lib.umich.edu/u/umhistmath/ABN7298.0001.001

Answer (score 3):

In many school curricula, especially the international ones, **circular measure**, often called **radian measure** are topics that refer to working with geometrical shapes, namely triangles and circles through the angle measurement known as radians. So for example, a circular measurement of $1/2$ would be $1/2$ radians or equivalently $28.6478898^{\circ}$ degrees.

More information about radians can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian).